# Puppet 3.8 recipe for installing package via Python pip

Tags: pip, puppet

Since I don't have Puppet 4.2 or later for the pip3 provider, what is an alternative approach to installing Python packages by hand via the 'pip3' command?

If I use the 'exec' approach, how do I control the package from being reinstalled all the time?  (i.e. how do I tell 'puppet apply' that the package is already installed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after dealing with this issue myself...

you can check if the package you wish to install is there

```
  exec { 'install python packages':
     command   => 'pip3 install flask flask_restful apiai',
     path => ['/usr/bin/'],
     unless  => '/usr/bin/test -f /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/app.py'
  }
```

if that does not work for you (maybe you wish to install a lot of packages), you can use a custom facter, and perform the installation only if that fact does not exist.
you need to do something like this -

```
if ($need_to_install == undef ) {

  exec { 'install python packages':
    command   => 'pip3 install flask flask_restful apiai; touch /root/installed.txt',
    path      => ['/usr/bin/'],
    before    => Exec['create custom facter'],
  }

  exec { 'create custom facter':
    command  => "mkdir -p /etc/facter/facts.d; echo 'need_to_install=false' > /etc/facter/facts.d/check_pip_install.txt",
    provider => shell,
  }

 }
```

BTW, you can also use this script to install pip3 package in the regular puppet way-
https://github.com/openstack-infra/puppet-pip/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider/package/pip3.rb